# GPG drops all non-self-signatures

Tags: gpg, signature

I want to import/refresh a gpg key from a keyserver including all non self-signatures.
Whenever I try to do this gpg says, for example

```
gpg: key <number>: number of dropped non-self-signatures: 24
[...]
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

As per the documentation this seems to be a desirable behavior in order to avoid importing keys flooded with bogus signatures, however I cannot get gpg to do what I want.

I have tried importing/refreshing keys with

```
gpg --verbose --import-options no-self-sigs-only --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <fingerprint>
```

but the output is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. The right flag was `--keyserver-options no-self-sigs-only`, so for example

```
gpg --verbose --keyserver-options no-self-sigs-only --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --refresh-keys
```